# Pass enum as function argument

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a simplified example illustrating my problem. The following gives me the: **error C2065: 'State' : undeclared identifier**

myclass.h

```
class MyClass
{
    enum class State { IDLE, WALK_RIGHT, WALK_LEFT };
    void SetState(State);
}
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"
void SetState(State state)
{
    //...
}
```

Any idea what's wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how you define a member function outside the class definition. You need

```
void MyClass::SetState(State state){
//   ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

The compiler will know to look for `State` in `MyClass` after it sees `MyClass::SetState` and realizes that this is a member function definition, so you don't have to write `MyClass::State` here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why wouldn't it? You're in a member function of `MyClass`, so `MyClass`'s members, including types, are in scope.

Comment: @hvd: I could have sworn they were not in scope in the parameter list. :( But I've verified that even in C++03 they are. Somehow I must have conflated this with the return type, many years ago, and managed not to spot my redundant qualifiers. :(